# How to add "Customdate" as link in dropdown list and open date upon click on it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to add customdate in dropdownlist and upon click on it,should open date in MVC.

JQuery

```
 $("#CustomDate").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        });
```

View

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Period, new List<SelectListItem>
                         {
                         ,
                          new SelectListItem {Value = "03/05/2018", Text = "Current Year" },
                          new SelectListItem {Value = "03/05/2017", Text = "Last Year" },
                          new SelectListItem {Value = "CustomDate", Text = "Custom Date"} // want to make CustomDate as link and want to open Date
                         },
                              new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Martin, I do not have an idea so I am looking for some ideas.

Comment: I'll give you an idea: Add a different class to the dropdown, attach a jquery change event handler, and in there look you the element with the 'CustomDate' value. When that condition is met, you can open your date picker.

Comment: @Martin, I added something like this but giving me error `new SelectListItem {Value = "CustomDate", Text = "Custom Date",new {@class="CustomDate" }}`

Comment: You need to add the class to the list, not to the element.

Comment: @Martin, but how to identify that which item item has selected from dropdown. Please provide me some sample which gives me some an idea to do this.

Comment: I've added an answer including a working example for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a different class to the dropdown, attach a jquery change event handler, and in there look you the element with the 'CustomDate' value. When that condition is met, you can open your date picker. See a working example below:

```js
$('.my-select').change(function(evt){
  if(this.value === 'Custom'){
    console.log('Custom Selected!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="my-select form-control">
  <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="Custom">Custom Date</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But how to implement datetime picker on it

Comment: Please help me with this. I updated the code `$('.my-select').change(function(evt){
 var selectedText = $(this).val();
  if(selectedText === 'Custom'){
     $(selectedText).datepicker({
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                });
  }
});` but the datepicker is not working

Comment: I don't think `$(selectedText)` is a valid jquery selector. You might want to initialize your datepicker outside of the event handler and have a separate element for it.

Comment: Yes Martin. How to get the date here.

Comment: Please help me. i am not getting it.